# Windows Server and Network Monitoring Tools

Tags: performance-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [windows server 2003 monitoring software combining SQL Server monitoring with CPU-IO stats](https://serverfault.com/questions/16639/windows-server-2003-monitoring-software-combining-sql-server-monitoring-with-cpu)

I am looking for tools to monitor our Windows servers in terms of disk/memory/cpu usage which also gives the notification options. I also have 2 VM hosts, I would like to monitor my server activities and performance. Can anyone recommend any tools for server monitoring?

Comment: This question could have a million answers because there are a million tools that do this. Try Googling for "network monitoring" and/or "server monitoring".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use use [cacti](http://www.cacti.net) for most of my monitoring. I've been looking at [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org) or [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) as a replacement, but there really are a ton of options.

Comment: I also use a Nagios / Cacti solution. http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/ for a Windows agent.

Answer (score 1):

I use [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg). You get a lot of different options for monitoring.